# ob_get_clean returns empty in php

Tags: php, parsing, buffer, output

I have large amount of data as string which includes text and lots of images.

The string includes specials tags like the following as well as normal text + images.

```
{{ title }}
```

I have a function which check if that string contains any php tags ?> or `<?php`

The function is

```
    protected function parseTxt($text){
        echo $text; //Gives me correct string
        ob_start();
        $result = eval('?>'.$text.'<?php ');                        
        if ($result === false){
          echo '<br />You have a syntax error.The snippet of text that contains 
the error has been output below:<br />';
          exit(str_replace(array('?>', '<?php '), '', $text));
        }
        return ob_get_clean();
      }
```

I get the str as null.

I have php 5.5 and I have increased memory limit to 512

Please suggest as I am not having any alternative clue.Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: i think not any buffer output please check your if()

Comment: Thanks but the thing is echo $text outputs the correct data.

Comment: try echo $text;  after ob_start need a output to buffer your all condition for output goes wrong

Comment: your `eval` may be returning false. Actually you are putting nothing to the buffer. if the result is false you have echo, but exits in the next line without hitting `ob_get_clean()` and if it is true the `echo $text;` is before the `ob_start();`

Comment: You realize that what you're doing is extremely dangerous, right? eval() is evil!

Comment: What $text are you sending into the function? Are you sure it's supposed to output anything?

Comment: Thanks guys. I think eval is the culprit.

Comment: Is there any other alternative function for eval to detect if the string contains any php code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be exiting before reaching `ob_get_clean()` . 
Also, dont use eval. Just dont. Why dont you just `echo $text` ?

P.S.

**eval is evil**

Comment: Yes it's exiting before reaching to ob_get_clean.Thanks.